# Searching for several Operating Systems with Get-ADComputer using LDAP Filter

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

I am using the below code to get Active Directory information with `Get-ADComputer` and it works fine

```
$computersFilter= "(&(operatingSystem=*Windows 7*)(name=*-*)(!name=V7-*)(!name=*-none)(!name=*-oncall)(!name=*-blackbaud)(!name=sc-win7-1)(!name=ut-swclient-01))"  

$computers= Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter $computersFilter -Property LastLogonDate | Select-Object Name, OperatingSystem,LastLogonDate 
$computers | Select Name, LastlogonDate, OperatingSystem | Export-Csv $ServiceTagsPath -NoTypeInformation
```

I'd like to also retrieve computers with operating systems **above Windows 7** (Windows 8, 8.1, and Windows 10) but when I change the filter like this:

```
(&(operatingSystem=*Windows 7*)(operatingSystem=*Windows 8*)(operatingSystem=*Windows 10*) ...
```

nothing is returned into the `$computers` variable

so what's the right way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way you have defined `$computersFilter`, if you look at it's type you will notice that it is of type `string`. And hence it doesn't return anything.

```
PS C> $computersFilter = "(&(operatingSystem=*Windows7*))(name=*-*)(!name=V7-*)(!name=*-none)(!name=*-oncall)(!name=*-blackbaud)(!name=sc-win7-1)(!name=ut-swclient-01))"
PS C> $computersFilter.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

`$computersFilter` should be declared as an array, so that the `-LDAPFilter` parameter is evaluated against the collection of object, like this -

```
PS C>$computersFilter = @("operatingSystem=*Windows7*", "name=*-*", "!name=V7-*", "!name=*-none", "!name=*-oncall", "!name=*-blackbaud", "!name=sc-win7-1", "!name=ut-swclient-01")
PS C> $computersFilter.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Comment: Thanks but I really need help getting several operating system versions - Windows 7 and up... and that's the part I'm having trouble with

Comment: You can add that as a new question, and we will be happy to help! :)

Comment: This was the intent of this question - in the title I stated that, although the question was poorly worded...

Comment: [-LDAPFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adcomputer?view=win10-ps) *Specifies an LDAP query string*. It doesn't make sense to suggest it needs to be an array. The used query string is wrong, not its type.

Comment: @rene - What you said is true, but what I meant is when the OP's `$computersFilter` is of type `string`, PowerShell will treat the entire `$$computersFilter` as one string and not as a collection. Hence, he doesn't get any output. But when he defines `$computersFilter` as a collection of strings( but `$computersFilter` becomes of type array), the `LDAPFilter` is able to iterate through the collection. Let me know, if I am making any sense here.

Comment: @OurManinBananas - The page for the new question is not found.

Comment: Yes, it is clear what you attempt, it is however not the (best) answer to the question of the OP. It is *not* a powershell problem and your partial solution is at best a hack.

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh: I have deleted that question, it was a duplicate, and showed not enough research into LDAP Query criteria and attributes

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh: question *undeleted* - and I have applied an answer